# Android: Selecting Layout/ How to format Design for Calculator

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how I would design a calculator with graphics similar to the following: [Design help for Calculator App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105656/design-help-for-calculator-app) or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.Appsys.PanecalST.

The key requirements:

- The buttons must be squared (it can pop out etc. but squares are more aesthetically pleasing than rectangles).
- It must be device compatible and retain square buttons upon orientation change

My problem is that Relative formatting (as I attempted) disorients the layout in different devices and is not as nice as I hoped. (i.e. trying to design the button to harbor no empty space in one device using relative instructions. One idea I fancy is putting a center button and orienting the others above left etc. so at the very least, no empty space is in the center.

Below is the designs I made:[image][image]

I prefer the first image but I neglected 0 (only buttons for 1-9). How would attempt at transforming these designs to code?

*I think I may use ImageButtons. I will include images based on density but how would I account for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for your calculator, use LinearLayout.
Link: Documentation will be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

Secondly, To Support multiple screen, 
This documentation will help, [documentation1](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), [documentation2](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

**What would I do in this situation?**

First of all, I would use the LinearLayout as my primary layout and give it an orientation > Vertical instead of RelativeLayout. This LinearLayout is for the whole screen (The output, the numbers and other functions).  Then for each line, say for the output screen, I would put it in another LinearLayout (Orientation Horizontal) inside the previous LinearLayout (NestedLayout). For numbers in each row, I would use a new LinearLayout.

For the second problem of yours, I would use buttons instead of images as images take large space in perspective of buttons which will unnecessary increase the app size. To support my button for multiple screen, I would use Weight option in android for buttons. [This stackoverflow answer has a nice description.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

I hope it helps. 
Cheers mate!

Comment: Wow that is a really nice idea, using weight! I will try to design it using your recommendations! Thanks so much for taking the time to give this advise! It probably improved my code by lots.

Comment: @Andy,Thanks and  Good luck mate :)